# F# method with byref parameter override

Tags: .net, methods, parameters, f#, byref

I'm trying to override a method with a byref parameter, the code below is an example

```
type Incrementor(z) =
    abstract member Increment : int byref * int byref -> unit
    default this.Increment(i : int byref,j : int byref) =
       i <- i + z

type Decrementor(z) =
    inherit Incrementor(z)
    override this.Increment(i : int byref,j : int byref) =
        base.Increment(ref i,ref j)

        i <- i - z
```

but the compiler give me this error:

```
A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.
```

I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Looks like a bug to me; I've filed a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that this is related to section II.9.4 of the CLI spec ([ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)) which says that you cannot instantiate generic types with `byref` parameters.

But where is the generic type instantiation? Guessing again, I think this might be related to the signature of the abstract `Increment` method, which has `int byref * int byref` tuple in it. But, I wouldn't have expected a tuple to be created when calling a method.

The actual problem only seems to be triggered by the `base.Increment(ref i, ref j)` call, if you remove this then it compiles. It will also compile if you remove one of the byref params, e.g. `abstract member Increment : int byref -> unit`.

You could use explicit `ref` types instead, but it's not clear from your example what you are trying to do.

```
type Incrementor(z) =
    abstract member Increment : int ref * int ref -> unit
    default this.Increment(i: int ref, j: int ref) =
       i := !i + z

type Decrementor(z) =
    inherit Incrementor(z)
    override this.Increment(i: int ref, j: int ref) =
        base.Increment(i, j)
        i := !i - z
```

Comment: Great. I don't know if the original problem is a compiler bug, it might be.